# How can I use a class' variables in another class?

Tags: python

I have a Drone class and a Building class. The Building class has two attributes named `x0` and `y0`. I want to use these two variables' values in the Drone class, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how that would be done.

Here's the code for Building:

```
class Building(Agent):

    def __init__(self, pos, x0, y0, model, request=False):  
        # Buildings won't have requests initially (set to false)
        super().__init__(pos, model)
        self.pos = pos
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.model = model
        self.request = request
```

And Drone:

```
class Drone(Agent):
    grid = None
    x = None
    y = None
    moore = True

    def __init__(self, name, model, x, y, speed, battery, heading, moore=True):
        super().__init__(name, model)
        self.name = name
        self.model = model
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.battery = battery
        self.heading = heading
        self.moore = moore



    def step(self):

        if self.name == 1:
            if self.x < Building.x0:
                self.x += 1
                new_pos = self.x, self.y
                self.model.grid.move_agent(self, new_pos)
            elif self.x > Building.x0:
                self.x -= 1
                new_pos = self.x, self.y
                self.model.grid.move_agent(self, new_pos)

            if self.y < Building.y0:
                self.y += 1
                new_pos = self.x, self.y
                self.model.grid.move_agent(self, new_pos)
            elif self.y > Building.y0:
                self.y -= 1
                new_pos = self.x, self.y
                self.model.grid.move_agent(self, new_pos)
```

Comment: Where in the drone class are you trying to use the variables?

Comment: I think you might be fundamentally misunderstanding some concepts of OOP (Object Oriented Programming). Both your `Building` and `Drone` class inherit from the `Agent` class, which means that `Drone` has no `x0` or `y0` variables. Now if a `Drone` object had access to a `Building` object, for example `building_obj` then you can access the variables using `building_obj.x0` and `building_obj.y0`. Perhaps try reading up on some concepts of OOP, and then look again at your code.

Comment: I accidentally left out a part of the code. I've addded it

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you understand the philosophy of object-oriented programming. If they both require the same information (x0, y0), then they should be the same object, or x0 and y0 should be established on the object they inherit from so that the child classes already have the data. E.g.
`agent.x0 = x0
 agent.y0 = y0`

so that both the building and the drone have this information on creation. But really, should consider refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0):
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0

class Drone:
    x = None
    y = None

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

   def step(self, building):
       if self.x < building.x0:
           etc
```

Your Building class doesn't have a class variable x0, y0. The instances of the Building class do. Thus your code of Building.x0 doesn't make sense.

```
building1 = Building(x_bldg, y_bldg)
drone1 = Drone(x_drn, y_drn)
drone1.step(building1)
```

Comment: A `drone` having a `building` attribute is kinda weird.  Instead, maybe `step` should have an `obstacle` parameter that you can pass a Building instance as the obstacle.

Comment: True, but I guess it depends on the context. If the building is the delivery spot then I would agree with you. If the building is the return home location, then maybe not.

Comment: The building is the delivery spot. How would the code for that look like?

Comment: Updated it based on the knowledge that the building is the delivery spot.